Merging different objects while keeping their parenting the same
Ok, so I am using copper cube and I am new to it. Now since copper cube accepts models in .fbx format, I have to export my blender models like that. Now, the .fbx format in copper cube requires the model to all be one, not separate objects. That's where the problem is.
In blender, I have a character with a sword who is rigged and animated. The character is parented to the metarig with automatic weights while the sword's parent set to bone. If I try to join the two, one of those parents has to be cleared, messing everything up.
So? Is there any way to join the two objects while not changing the parents?
Someone please help me on this.

Yep, it helped. Although I use the node linking thing of Copper Cube now, this one also does the trick. Thanks.
